# Controlling batch size to hint scheduler performance

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I would like to manually tune how big my mini-batches (in terms of cardinality) are. A way to set max number of events would be enough, but if there's a way to set max/min that would be better.

The reason I want to mess around with this is because I know for a fact that my processing code does not scale linearly.

In my particular case I'm not doing time aggregation, so I don't really care about time-frame aggregation, but depleting the "input queue" as soon as possible (by hinting the engine how many elements to process at a time).

However, if there's no way to set the max/min batch cardinality directly, I could probably workaround the limitation using a dummy time aggregation approach by stamping my input data before Spark consumes it.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you consume data from?

Comment: Eventhub (https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark)

Comment: Please take a look at this topic https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/enable-back-pressure-make-your-spark-streaming-production-lan-jiang/ It should also apply to  your input